# Como checar se existe um usuário existe e impedir a criação de login?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de login em Pyhton, e travei num certo ponto. Eu quero criar um código que cheque dentro de uma lista todos os usuários existentes, e avise ao novo usuário que o login que ele está tentando criar já existe. Eu consegui fazer apenas com um único usuário dentro da lista, mas quando tento por mais de um, aí já não sei o que fazer. Aqui está o programa que eu estou criando:

````
usuario1 = []
senha2 = []
usuario2 = []
loginex = ['usuarionumero1']
senhaex = ['admin']

def checagem():
    if usuario2 != usuario1:
        print('Login inválido.')
    elif senha1 != senha2:
        print('Login inválido.')
    else:
        if usuario1 == usuario2:
            print('Login efetuado com sucesso!')
        elif senha1 == senha2:
            print('Login efetuado com sucesso!')

def login():
    print('LOGIN')
    usuario2.append(input('Digite seu usuário: '))
    senha2.append(input('Digite sua senha: '))

def checagemex():
    if usuario2 != loginex:
        print('Login inválido.')
    elif senhaex != senha2:
        print('Login inválido.')
    else:
        if loginex == usuario2:
            print('Login efetuado com sucesso!')
        elif senhaex == senha2:
            print('Login efetuado com sucesso!')

def criacaologin():
    usuario1.append(input('Digite seu nome de usuário: '))
    senha1.append(input('Digite sua senha: '))
    #for usuarios in loginex:
    while usuario1 == loginex:
        usuario1.clear()
        usuario1.append(input('Usuário já cadastrado.\n Digite seu nome de usuário: '))
        senha1.append(input('Digite sua senha: '))


print('Bem vindo ao sistema de dados.')
p1 = input('Você já possui uma conta em nosso sistema? R: ')
if p1 == 'Sim':
    login()
    checagemex()

else:
    if p1 =='Não':
        print('Sistema de cadastro de usuário.')
        criacaologin()

print('LOGIN')
usuario2.append(input('Digite seu usuário: '))
senha2.append(input('Digite sua senha: '))
checagem()```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei grato!
````

Answer (score -2):

Sugiro que crie um arquivo.txt para cadastrar os usuários e senhas... Dessa forma toda vez que executar o programa a lista vai ser resetada e todos os usuários e senhas serão perdidos. Por isso que sempre que executa o código ele permite vc cadastrar o mesmo usuário.

pra ser mais exato, todo usuário cadastrado nas listas vazias que você criou no começo, não persiste ao rodar o código novamente...

segue um vídeo de exemplo do que você quer fazer de forma MUITO simples que ajuda MUITO!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksCYvv9bI3Y&ab_channel=DevAprender

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Veja se funciona assim:

```
usuarios = []
senhas = []

def checagem(usuario):
    if usuario in usuarios:
        print('Login existente.')
        return True
    else:
        print('Login inexistente/Username disponível.')
        return False

def autenticacao(indice,senha):
    if senhas[indice] == senha:
        print('Usuário autenticado')
        return True
    else:
        print('Erro de senha')
        return False

def login():
    print('LOGIN')
    usuario = input('Digite seu usuário: ')
    senha = input('Digite sua senha: ')
    if checagem(usuario):
        indice = usuarios.index(usuario)
        autenticacao(indice,senha)
        
    else:
        print("Entre com um usuário válido!")

def criacaologin():
    usuario = input('Digite seu nome de usuário: ')
    senha = input('Digite a sua senha: ')
    
    if checagem(usuario) == False:            
        usuarios.append(usuario)
        senhas.append(senha)
        print('Usuário criado!')
    else:
        print('Username Indisponível')

print('Bem vindo ao sistema de dados.')
p1 = input('Você já possui uma conta em nosso sistema? R:[Sim/Não] ')
if p1 == 'Sim':
    login()

else:
    if p1 =='Não':
        print('Sistema de cadastro de usuário.')
        criacaologin()
```

Comment: Rapaz, funcionou direitinho! Muito obrigado :D

Comment: Caso a resposta tenha ajudado, marque-a como 'aceita' para que possa ficar relevante para outros usuários.